# Одинаковая ширина flex и обычных секций

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Есть три секции, последняя - flexbox, содержащий три div блока. Почему-то при установке одинакового для всех секций max-width ширина секции А и секции B одинакова, а секция C, содержащая дивы, (ударение на У) уже. Пробовал использовать % вместо пикселей, авось что-то изменится, не изменилось)
    https://codepen.io/Boryamba/pen/oNgjoOe

Также хотел дать секции C h2 элемент, но т.к. секция сделана в флексбоксе заголовок перемещается на тот же уровень, что и дивы.
 https://codepen.io/Boryamba/pen/bGNVYyZ

Вопросы: как выровнять секции А, B и C, чтобы имели одинаковую ширину? Можно ли поместить заголовок в секции Ц над дивами без grid layout?

```
<section id="section-a">
    <h2 class="section-head">Section A</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</section>
<section id="section-b">
    <h2 class="section-head">Section B</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</section>
<section id="section-c">
    <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque nemo adipisci quibusdam
        perferendis provident impedit?</div>
    <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Omnis sed velit maiores sequi quibusdam
        autem.</div>
    <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, animi earum natus mollitia ex magni!
    </div>
</section>
```

```
.section-head {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#section-a {
    padding         : 1.5em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color           : #fff;
    text-align      : center;
    max-width       : 900px;
    margin          : 0 auto;
}

#section-b {
    padding         : 1.5em;
    background-color: rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color           : #000;
    text-align      : center;
    max-width       : 900px;
    margin          : 0 auto;
}

#section-c {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#section-c .box1, #section-c .box3 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

#section-c .box2 {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-a">
    <h2 class="section-head">Section A</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</section>
<section id="section-b">
    <h2 class="section-head">Section B</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</section>
<section id="section-c">
    <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque nemo adipisci quibusdam
        perferendis provident impedit?</div>
    <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Omnis sed velit maiores sequi quibusdam
        autem.</div>
    <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, animi earum natus mollitia ex magni!
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

Либо устанавливаем box-sizing: border-box для целой страницы, либо убираем отступы по бокам у секции А и В

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Или

```
#section-a, #section-b {
    padding: 1.5em 0;
}
```